# One download many updates

Tags: updates

I have several VM all running Ubuntu 18.04 when updates are required I need to execute the same process on each machine.

Is there a way where I can download the latest patch updates for 18.04 and apply it to several machines?

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080902/installing-updates-on-multiple-ubuntu-machines

Comment: Also, this thread mentions using `dsh` instead: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2199351#post_12899716

Comment: This seems precisely one use case for Unattended Upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, configure your host as server for AptCacherNg tool following this https://wiki.debian.org/AptCacherNg and configure the VMs as clients, you will get what you wanted.